# How do I whitelist sites on a browser running the Bluhell Firewall add-on?

Tags: browser, firewall, firefox-extensions, bluhell

I am running a browser (Waterfox, a Firefox clone optimized for 64-bit Windows OS) with the [Bluhell Firewall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bluhell-firewall/versions/) installed. I cannot find any obvious way to whitelist sites (such as stackoverflow.com :-).

Does this add-on support whitelisting, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does this add-on support whitelisting?

It would appear not, if you read the (recent) comments:

> Bluhell really lacks a whitelist feature, it desperately needs it. **I frankly don't understand why the developer so stubbornly refuses to implement it**. Otherwise Bluhell is perfect.

and

> Bluhell works quite well....but I do come across pages that are blocked that I don't want blocked. **Can the developer please comment if a white-list feature is in the works**?

and

> I'm still giving Bluhell 4 stars because Bluhell work REALLY GREAT!!!! --- other than the glaring need for a White List to deal with the very small handful of sites that need to be included in the list that load w/out any notification from Bluhell there's a problem but will NOT work properly w/ Bluehell enabled.
>
> Of course 5-stars would be what I'd rank Bluhell with a White List available to deal with the a very small handful of sites (only two sites that I'm aware of so far that load fine but Bluhell causes to not function properly) and because the list would clearly be very limited in size would presumably NOT appreciably slow down the performance of Buehell. As I've said before, clearly Bluehell does maintain a White List behind the scenes for all sites that Bluhell blocks but is then instead "allowed" by the user via the Bluhell prompt to do so. The problem is that some sites are not prompted by Bluhell so the user would presume that the site will function properly when in actuality the site is partially disabled by Bluhell which would be resolved with the ability to add the site to the White List that Bluhell already maintains for some sites "allowed" by the user anyway.

Source [Reviews for Bluhell Firewall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bluhell-firewall/reviews/)